# What is the difference between "palazzo" and "palace"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, translation, confusables

I have noticed that *palazzo* is used not only in Italian but in English too.

So what is the difference between *palazzo*, and *palace* (in English)?

Comment: Isn't *palazzo* where we get *plaza* (cf. German *Platz*).

Comment: @Robusto *plaza* comes from the Spanish, *palazzo* comes from the Italian

Comment: Ultimately, they all come from πλατεῖα ὁδός (broad way).

Comment: @RegDwight: Not true. The ultimate origin of all these words is from *Mons Palatinus* (the Palatine Hill) in Rome! The first "palace" was the Imperial palace on this hill in Ancient Rome.

Comment: @RegDwight: Are you referring to the origin of _palazzo_ and _palace_?

Comment: @Noldorin: let's meet in the middle. *Platz*, *place*, *piazza*, etc. do come from *πλατεῖα ὁδός*, but *Palast*, *palace*, *palazzo*, etc. do come from *Mons Palatinus*. That should make everybody happy. (As it is actually correct.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I was kind of addressing Robusto (after seeing *Platz*), but got totally carried away. Kudos to Noldorin.

Comment: @RegDwight: Yeah, absolutely! :) I was only referring to the Roman-derived names in the question, but well done for clarifying the "false friend" (*plaza*, etc.) that @Robusto mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a palace is the official residence of a sovereign (or, by extension, a dignitary). Informally, it may also mean “a building that looks like a palace”, i.e. a vast, beautiful and richly-decorated house.

The NOAD has for *palazzo*: “a palatial building, esp. in Italy”. So, I expect that the main difference is this *“in Italy”*. Other than that, I think it's quite close in meaning, at least to the informal meaning of *palace*.

As for usage, *palazzo* is much less used than *palace*: the Corpus of Contemporary American English has 7622 occurrences of “palace” vs 597 for “palazzo” or “palazzi”.

Answer (score 7):

"Palazzo" is mainly used in English to communicate that the building is called a palazzo in the regional language of its location.

Answer (score 0):

Palazzo is, indeed, an Italian Palace, but it could also be an impressive public building or a private residence( in english).